# MXP to Interlaken

Tags: transit, trains, switzerland, milan

My flight lands at MXP at 10AM June 21st, 2024. It's an international flight from Canada.
I need to go to Interlaken on the same day.
Looks like the schedule is not available yet. Also looks like there will be a repair work on the Domodossola line.
When should I look into booking this? what's the best way to go there?

Comment: Sbb.ch gives several options on that day, you could book those right now.

Comment: SBB currently only shows a route that involves a detour via Lugano. This because Italian schedules for June are not on line yet.

Answer (score 2):

MXP is not a convenient airport for Interlaken.

But the best route is going to be: Bus to Domodossola, then train from there. And I would expect schedules to be available May or so.

Info on the bus you will find here: https://www.comazzialibus.com/ComazziAlibus/?locale=EN

And schedules for the trains you will find on [www.sbb.ch](http://www.sbb.ch). But schedules for June are not complete yet.